# Schema.org jobposting location: multiple countries

Tags: schema.org

If a job can be performed remotely across a region, such as EMEA or Asia, should each country be written out or is it enough to just specify the region, such as EMEA?

Answer (score 1):

The **[guide for JobPosting Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#definitions)** directly reports this to the following:

> **jobLocation - Place**
>
> The physical location(s) of the business where the
>   employee will report to work (such as an office or worksite), not the
>   location where the job was posted.
>
> **Multiple physical locations**
>
> If the job has multiple locations, add multiple jobLocation properties
>   in an array. Google will choose the best location to display based on
>   the job seeker's query.

Thus, you need to create structured data for each workplace in each country where the vacancy is available. To specify a place of job, use the type **PostalAddress** as a locality embedded in the property **jobLocation**. For example:

```
"jobLocation": {
  "@type": "Place",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
```